# How i do a print for a specific variable in a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

i'm looking to print the an specific name and the result of a function that a i did. I'm using this code:

```
arrays=[qda_confusion_matrix, Knn_5_confusion_matrix, Tree_Boo_confusion_matrix]
names=['QDA', '5-NN', 'Tree con Boosting']
for name in names:
    for array in arrays:
        print(name,'\n')
        Spe=Specificity(array)
```

As you can see, I want to do the function `Specificity(array)` in each of the arrays that the variable arrays has. Nevertheless, I also want that for the fist array, that in this example is `qda_confusion_matrix` appear the name of the model, that is `QDA` and then the result.

The result from this code is:

```
QDA 

Specificity: 0.235
QDA 

Specificity: 0.059
QDA 

Specificity: 0.306
5-NN 

Specificity: 0.235
5-NN 

Specificity: 0.059
5-NN 

Specificity: 0.306
Tree con Boosting 

Specificity: 0.235
Tree con Boosting 

Specificity: 0.059
Tree con Boosting 

Specificity: 0.306
```

This result is wrong because what i want is:

```
QDA
Specificity: 0.235

5-NN
Specificity: 0.059

Tree con Boosting
Specificity: 0.306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to loop over both lists in parallel

```
arrays=[qda_confusion_matrix, Knn_5_confusion_matrix, Tree_Boo_confusion_matrix]
names=['QDA', '5-NN', 'Tree con Boosting']

for value, name in zip(arrays, names):
    print(name)
    Spe = Specificity(value)
```

Comment: Thanks Buran, your answer fix my problem. I will check the question.